# contenteditable div height change working inside design

Tags: javascript, css

Hopefully this is somewhat simple to figure out. I have a list of items of an unknown height and a content editable div underneath it. I need to figure out how to resize the list when the content editable div gets bigger with content. Is there a css trick that I missed somewhere? Do I need to listen for an event? What's the best solution here?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdparmeter/q78jN/) to show what I'm talking about.

here's html structure in the fiddle just cause it makes me post code with a fiddle.

```
<div class="containerDiv" ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <p>{{item.message}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="inputDiv" contenteditable></div>
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
</div>
```

For example look at the facebook chat window. How does it resize when you have multiple lines of text before you send the message? Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to encapsulate your list in a div and let that div be dynamically handled by CSS.

You would then need to modify your height property and make the same 'auto'.

Next, provide a min-height if you require.

```
containerDiv {
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:auto;
    width:150px;
    min-height:100px;
}
.containerDiv ul {
    height:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q78jN/1/

Comment: your adding more html and css for default behavior. I need the list to resize/ get smaller when the contenteditable div gets taller with content. or in other words I have a container 100 px tall the content editable div is bottom justified and fixed to the bottom of the container. the content above the editable div needs to resize and scroll if necessary when the height of the editable div changes.